# Group By in MySQL Pivot Table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am creating a pivot table like this :

```
    MONTH   A       B       C       D       E 
     01     NULL    NULL    11.600  NULL    NULL
     01     11.600  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
     02     NULL    NULL    6.000   NULL    NULL
     03     NULL    NULL    14.667  NULL    NULL
```

and when i'm using Group By in my query, the table changes like this:

```
   MONTH    A      B       C        D       E
   01      NULL    NULL    11.600   NULL    NULL
   02      NULL    NULL    6.000    NULL    NULL
   03      NULL    NULL    14.667   NULL    NULL
```

This is the table i'm looking for :

```
   MONTH    A      B       C        D       E
   01      11.600  NULL    11.600   NULL    NULL
   02      NULL    NULL    6.000    NULL    NULL
   03      NULL    NULL    14.667   NULL    NULL
```

This is my query :

```
    SELECT 
DISTINCT MONTH , 
CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C001" THEN PWT END AS A,
CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C002" THEN PWT END AS B,
CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C003" THEN PWT END AS C,
CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C004" THEN PWT END AS D,
CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C005" THEN PWT END AS E

FROM `keyperformanceindicator`

INNER JOIN pilot ON keyperformanceindicator.ID_Pilot = pilot.ID_Pilot
INNER JOIN cabang ON keyperformanceindicator.ID_Cabang = cabang.ID_Cabang
INNER JOIN 
(

  SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT( PilotStationDate, '%m' ) AS MONTH , 
   FORMAT( SUM(`PilotWaitingTime`) / COUNT('PilotStationDate'), 3 ) AS PWT, 
   COUNT( 'PilotStationDate' ) AS jumlah

  FROM keyperformanceindicator
  INNER JOIN pilot ON keyperformanceindicator.ID_Pilot = pilot.ID_Pilot
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( PilotStationDate, '%m' )

)x ON DATE_FORMAT( PilotStationDate, '%m' ) = x.Month

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(PilotStationDate, '%m')
ORDER BY  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT_WS( '', PilotStationDate, ' ', PilotStationTime ) ) ASC
```

and lastly. How can i change the NULL to 0?

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Coalesce** function with the case to change null values to 0.

```
Coalesce ((CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C001" THEN PWT END),0) AS A,
Coalesce ((CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C002" THEN PWT END),0) AS B,
Coalesce ((CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C003" THEN PWT END),0) AS C,
Coalesce ((CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C004" THEN PWT END),0) AS D,
Coalesce ((CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C005" THEN PWT END),0) AS E
```

**Updated Query:**

```
    SELECT 
     MONTH , 
    coalesce((max(CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C001" THEN PWT END)),0) AS A,
    coalesce((max(CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C002" THEN PWT END)),0) AS B,
    coalesce((max(CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C003" THEN PWT END)),0) AS C,
    coalesce((max(CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C004" THEN PWT END)),0) AS D,
    coalesce((max(CASE WHEN Cabang.ID_Cabang = "C005" THEN PWT END)),0) AS E

    FROM `keyperformanceindicator`

    INNER JOIN pilot ON keyperformanceindicator.ID_Pilot = pilot.ID_Pilot
    INNER JOIN cabang ON keyperformanceindicator.ID_Cabang = cabang.ID_Cabang
    INNER JOIN 
    (

      SELECT 
       DATE_FORMAT( PilotStationDate, '%m' ) AS MONTH , 
       FORMAT( SUM(`PilotWaitingTime`) / COUNT('PilotStationDate'), 3 ) AS PWT, 
       COUNT( 'PilotStationDate' ) AS jumlah

      FROM keyperformanceindicator
      INNER JOIN pilot ON keyperformanceindicator.ID_Pilot = pilot.ID_Pilot
      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( PilotStationDate, '%m' )

    )x ON DATE_FORMAT( PilotStationDate, '%m' ) = x.Month

    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(PilotStationDate, '%m')
    ORDER BY  UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT_WS( '', PilotStationDate, ' ', PilotStationTime ) ) ASC
```

Comment: it's COALESCE. Thanks. but my main problem is not solved yet

Comment: Can you share create query of table "keyperformanceindicator" with some  data, So that I can work on your query accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much @Code-Monk

Answer (score 0):

That's more difficult than it needs to be.

`GROUP BY` without some aggregate is not proper SQL.

```
SELECT  month,
        SUM(A),
        SUM(B),
        ...
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY month;
```

should be all you need.  `COALESCE()` does not seem to be required for this question.

`SUM()` (and many other aggregates) simply ignore any `NULL` cells when doing the arithmetic.

Another point:  `COUNT('PilotStationDate')` is "wrong".  It counts how many times the literal string 'PilotStationDate' is not null.  Perhaps you meant `COUNT(PilotStationDate)`?

But then why SUM the Times, but COUNT the Dates?  Won't it work to simply AVG the Times?